# jQuery GalleryView support for links/href

Tags: jquery, slideshow, galleryview

I've upgraded to jQuery GalleryView 2.1.1 and it doesn't seem to support ahref tags on the images.  Is there a workaround for this?  I want to be able to display the title on image mouseover and redirect to another page onclick.

Comment: the link from the plugins page @ http://plugins.jquery.com/project/galleryview seems to be broken and without any demos to example code for this jQuery plugin.

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/node/13734

Comment: @Doug: image tag don't have href attribute, ps, provide your current help, if you want a quick help.

Answer (score 3):

> - **demo:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/jquery-galleryview-support-for-links-href/

```
$('#gallery .panel img').hover(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<a href="' + this.src + '" target="_blank"/>');
}, function() {
    $(this).unwrap('<a></a>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

here is what i did: i used the panel-overlay as the object to be clicked.
i added an A tag to it so i can use its href attribute (see bellow)

```
<li><span class="panel-overlay"><a href="your_link_here" ></a></span><img  src="pic.jpg"  alt=""/></li>
```

in the css file i made sure the panel-overlay covered the entire image and made it transparent.also added a hand cursor to it.

```
.panel .overlay-background { height: 666px; cursor:pointer;background: none; }
```

finally, inside the page's $(document).ready function i added:

```
   $(".panel-overlay").click(function() {
    //get the link href 
    var link = jQuery("a", this).attr('href');
    window.location.href = link;
   });
```

hope this helps someone out there..
cheers :-)